# For any map $g:V \rightarrow W$ is $\dim{\operatorname{im}\,g} \leq \dim{V}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear Algebra there is the Rank-nullity-theorem which states that for a linear map $f:V \rightarrow W$ we have

$$\dim{\operatorname{im}\,f}+\dim{\operatorname{ker}\,f}=\dim{V},$$

which implies

$$\dim{\operatorname{im}\,f} \leq \dim{V}.$$

Does this hold true for general maps $g:V \rightarrow W$?

I was thinking that this is probably not the case as there should be some surjective mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which exploits the density of $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps something along the lines of a space-filling curve? I know there is the notion of fractal dimensionality and I realized that this question probably hinges on the definition of dimensionality. I would appreciate someone clarification or some reference, which might clarify this.

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything similiar by search.

Comment: What does this have to do with covering spaces?

Comment: For a general map $im(f)$ doesn't need to be a linear subspace, so talking about its dimension might result meaningless

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about maps between infinite dimensional vector spaces, hence the deleted answer.

Comment: let's say $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m>n$. Can there be a surjective $g$ ?

Comment: Space filling curves are a well known example. So yes.

Comment: Use `\to` instead of `\arrow`

Comment: It is well known that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equal for all $m$ and $n$. This says by definition that we in fact have bijections between them.

Comment: thanks, this is what I am looking for! Are there any well-known proofs for that?

Comment: I guess the whole question boils down to how you define dimensionality. If we are talking about the cardinality of the sets $V, W$ then obviously $W$ can't have a bigger cardinality than $V$ or $g$ wouldn't be a mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is clearly: no, as we can construct a bijection $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m>n$.